How would you test RegisterApplicationRestart()
I've been struggling with this little issue for years and thought it was time to tackle it.
I have a few MFC/C++ apps that sit running in the system tray. Occasionally, they just go away. It looks like we are getting a bunch of WM_CLOSE messages and I believe WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION.
The reason I say "I believe" is because I've never been able to duplicate this. But I'm finally getting an inkling that it is because something else has installed an update. It doesn't restart the computer - if it did, my application would come back at restart. My app goes away and never comes back.
So, it is possible that RegisterApplicationRestart() will solve my problem and relaunch the program.
The question I have is, how do I test this so that a shutdown due to an update will restart the app? Any thoughts on triggering some kind of update or emulation of an update that would force programs to close?

Are you closing your app unconditionally when it receives WM_ENDSESSION? Are you looking at its wParam and not closing when it is FALSE?

@RemyLebeau, yes, currently, that's what I'm doing. I see now that RegisterApplicationRestart() is likely the fix I'm looking for.
What's most at issue is, how do I test my code? Write a program that triggers a Restart Manager session? Or is there some tricky way in Windows to emulate what an update of that sort would do.
